# NUXT modify data after transition is finished

Tags: nuxt.js

I have modified NUXT default default mode from `in-out` to `''` just to be able create a more smooth page effect where both pages do their transition at the same time... while I thought it was cool it brought a problem... now my to page is being mounted before getting into view for the customer so I can not use the mounted hook anymore to fire more effects...

Now what I need to find is a way to change my data when the transition finish...

I have found that I can do on the page component:

```
transition: {
    afterEnter (el) {
     //my effect here
    }
  },
```

But I have no way to modify the data from this hook...

is there any way to affect the component data after my transition has finished?

Comment: Are you sure that `''`is valid? Tried with `out-in`?

Comment: Also, what do you want to modify?

Comment: in-out wait for 1 to finish in order to fired the other one... I need both of transitions to be run together

Comment: What I mean, is that I'm not sure that `''` is doing anything at all. Either it fallbacks to something or it is just not working. Usually, you'll do a FLIP animation or alike if you want to have a 50-50 transition.

Comment: it is valid because I read it on the documentation https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/transitions/ (check transition mode section)